# Intersect and MBR in POSTGIS and Mysql

Tags: postgis, intersection

I would like to know if POSTGIS and MySql with Spatial Extension use true geometry to find intersections/overlaps between geospatial objects. But i don't find it precisely in the documentation. I know that doing an ST_Intersects is more precise than only using the && command.

I want to know if in this example the round geospatial objects would intersect/overlap: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13064345/example.jpg
The squares are the minimum bounding boxes, they overlap. But i am not sure of the ouput in POSTGIS and MySQl. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostGIS, the `&&` operator uses the MBR to test for for overlap of two geometries.  `ST_Intersects` uses the true geometry.

In MySQL versions prior to 5.6.1, `ST_Intersects` used the bounding box instead of actual geometry to test for intersection.  From MySQL 5.6.1 onward, `ST_Intersects` uses the actual geometry.  The MySQL function `Intersects` still uses the MBR.

In your example image, you should use ST_Intersects in PostGIS, or MySQL 5.6.1+ to test intersection of the two circles.

Answer (score 1):

In PostGIS it is the real geometries that is compared. First it sorts out all overlapping boundin boxes, with index if present. Then it compares the real geometries of the candidates.